# Table layout is not behaving as expected

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have this code building a piece of UI:

```
    // Trying to fix the layout by setting the defaults for the next row.
    layout.row().expand(false, false).fill(false).colspan(4);

    Label playerLabel = new Label(Settings.playerName + "  " + playerScore, skin, "defaultWhite");
    layout.add(playerLabel).colspan(1);

    Label historyLabel = new Label(getHistory(), skin, "defaultWhite");
    historyLabel.setAlignment(2);
    layout.add(historyLabel).colspan(2).expandX();

    Label cpuLabel = new Label(cpuScore + "  CPU", skin, "defaultWhite");
    layout.add(cpuLabel).colspan(1);

    layout.row();
```

I expected it to make the player and cpu scores get pushed to the sides and the history label to get the remaining space, but this is what it's doing:

[image: Game UI]

Am I doing something wrong here? I can't see what could be the error.

If you want to take a look on the rest of the code, it's on [github](https://github.com/theosirian/ppioo), or just ask and I'll provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the entire layout with one table, try nesting tables where each inner table is a row. This eliminates the need for colspan all together and you can create columns and lay out each row table however you want without affecting the other rows.

Comment: That's what I'm gonna go with, I also managed to make it work like I wanted by using the uniform() method on the score labels, but using more tables gives me more control over the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use more tables as suggested in the accepted answer, I managed to get it working by calling [uniform()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Cell.html#uniform--) in the score cells, like so:

```
layout.row().expand(false, false).fill(false).colspan(4);

Label playerLabel = new Label(Settings.playerName + "  " + playerScore, skin, "defaultWhite");
layout.add(playerLabel).colspan(1).uniform();

Label historyLabel = new Label(getHistory(), skin, "defaultWhite");
historyLabel.setAlignment(2);
layout.add(historyLabel).colspan(2).expandX();

Label cpuLabel = new Label(cpuScore + "  CPU", skin, "defaultWhite");
layout.add(cpuLabel).colspan(1).uniform();

layout.row();
```